# Changing sourceRoot always generates an app subfolder when I generate a folder with angular cli

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, angular6, angular-cli-v6

I'm using angular 6, I have change the sourceRoot of my angular.json file to "src/app/web-portal" which is the source of my app. But when I try to generate a new componenet with ng g c component_name it creates it under src/app/web-portal/app/component_name when the path should be src/app/web-portal/component_name without the last app folder.
This is my angular.json configuration.

```
      "root": "src/app",
      "sourceRoot": "src/app/web-portal",
```

Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9370) posted for this.

There are 2 solutions suggested :

```
"appRoot" : "web-portal"
```

or use this command instead

```
ng g c ../component_name
```

Comment: ng g c ../component_name works. But where do you have to configure "appRoot" : "web-portal", there's no such property in angular.json?

Comment: it used to work in older versions back in angular-cli.json. it is not mentioned in the new CLI documentation. I guess it is deprecated now. I used it in an older version and it did the trick.

Comment: another GitHub issue : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/7775 mentions :
No document get updated as I mentioned above. But you can use it this way for an app "common" sibling to the default "app".

    },
    {
      "name": "common",
      "appRoot": "common",
      "root": "src",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
they mention that it is undocumented  so you can try and see if it works